# PyCharm Run/Debug configuration, do I really need one per file/tab?

Tags: python, pycharm, run-configuration

I just got started with python and Im using PyCharm Build #PC-201.8743.11. I have 2 files in my project and Im using the Pipenv interpreter.

Each file has its own working Run/Debug configuration. Whats driving me mad is that if I switch file/tab I also have to manually switch Run/Debug configuration.

Is there no way to use one Run/Debug configuration per project or alternatively have the configuration locked per file so it switches the Run/Debug configuration as I change tabs?

Thanks
Sahand

Comment: `Alt+Shift+F9/F10` could make it simpler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Run/Debug configuration doesn't follow which file you have open because generally within a project you will only have one (or not many) entry points, while the rest of your files are modules/libraries/helpers/whatever you want to call them.

If your two files are unrelated, then it sounds like you should have two different projects for them, in which case each project would have a Run/Debug configuration. If they are related, but are just two different entry points, then unfortunately you will have to make sure you are running with the correct Configuration each time you want to run. Depending on the complexity of your setup, this can be as simple as right-clicking in the file itself and selecting "Run <filename>".

Comment: guess this is why I should not of skipped the python coding convention part of the tutorial :)